# Using Java Void type in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a Java function that requires me to pass a `Void` parameter due to type constraints. Something like:

```java
void foo(Void v) {
    // do something
}
```

Now I would like to call that function from Kotlin, but the compiler complains that the types are not compatible when I call it with `null` like I would from Java:

```kotlin
foo(null);
```

What do I have to pass to that function so that the Kotlin compiler accepts it?

**Update:** the actual code looks like this:

```kotlin
fun foo(): Map<String, Void> {
    return mapOf(Pair("foo", null))
}
```

**Update:** using `null as Void` actually doesn't work either:

```
kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type java.lang.Void
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the variable to null before hand? Is the function using an INT or OBJECT? If so maybe set it to NULL before you try and access it or alter it. Is this a method you're calling or are you inheriting this from another class?

Comment: actually I'm inheriting a function that is supposed to return `Map<String, Void>` and want to `return mapOf(Pair("foo", null))`

Comment: What is the exact error message given by the compiler? I wasn't able to reproduce the problem in an isolated sample, i.e. you should be able to pass null to a `Void` parameter

Comment: @AlexanderUdalov `Error:(33, 16) Kotlin: Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is kotlin.Map<kotlin.String, kotlin.Nothing?> but kotlin.Map<kotlin.String, java.lang.Void> was expected`. This is with the Beta 2 version of Kotlin.

Comment: Did you try changing it to `Void?`?

Comment: Perhaps `null as Void`?

Comment: The `Void()` constructor is private and just `Void` doesn't work either. `null as Void` warns that "This cast can never succeed".

Comment: Hmm.. when I try this (java: `class Go { void foo(Void v) {} }` and kotlin: `Go().foo(null)`), the compiler does not complain, and execution succeeds. When debugging in the `foo` method, the `v` value is `null`. Tested with `1.0.0-beta-2423`.

Comment: Strange, I've tried to pass the `null` as the value of 'Void v' argument of Java method from Kotlin and it worked w/o any complaints from compiler. Which Kotlin version are you using?

Comment: ... just stumbled upon this question... why would anyone ever want to use a `Map` having `Void?` as a value type? The values can only be `null` that way ("black magic" aside), so why even bother? Why not just using a `Set` instead?

Answer (score 6):

Haven't had a chance to try it, but based purely on your exception the following code should work:

```
fun foo(): Map<String, Void?> {
    return mapOf(Pair("foo", null))
}
```

Explanation: `Map<String, Void>` is expecting there to be no `null` values. But you're creating a `Pair` with a `null` value. People are suggesting invoking the java method requiring `Void` with `null` which should work as far as I'm aware, but for the `Pair` constructor you're using you definitely need to explicitly state that the `Map` can contain null values.

**Edit:** my bad for necro-ing, didn't think about the date until after. :(

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Definitely use a nullable type if you want to pass null.

Comment: This is one special case I think kotlins should handle. Void type will always be null

Answer (score 3):

Try to update your Kotlin plugin. I'm on '1.0.0-beta-1103-IJ143-27' and the following code compiles without any complaints/warnings:

```
// On Java side
public class Test {
    public void test(Void v) {

    }
}

// On Kotlin side
fun testVoid() {
    Test().test(null)
}
```

Comment: my plugin is actually even more up-to-date: `1.0.0-beta-2423-IJ143-13` but the problem still persists

Comment: I have the same plugin version as aga (`1.0.0-beta-1103-IJ143-27`). I'm using `IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.1`, and the code posted by aga works in my environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had came up with 2 solutions, both of them compiles (under Kotlin 1.1.2-3).

You might need this (not changing your method signature but it doesn't work):

```
fun foo(): Map<String, Void> {
  return mapOf(Pair("foo", throw Exception("Why? Why you call me")))
}
```

Or something like (changing your signature and it works):

```
fun foo(): Map<String, Void?> {
  return mapOf(Pair("foo", null as Void?))
}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Well, simple workaround

```
companion object {
    private val void = Object()
}
```

(move it out of the companion object when it needs to be "protected")
It's not exactly a Void type, but it's just as useless.

I am using it this way because I have issues with Collections.synchronizedSet(HashSet()), an occasional missing item, so thought to try java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap instead.