# Android Studio Kotlin Null Pointer Exception while updating Firestore Database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, nullpointerexception

I've recently stumbled upon a runtime error that crashes my application for whatever reason and I cannot get to the bottom of it. Basically I am updating user profile data by storing it in a hashmap. This is what the user class looks like:

```
@Parcelize
data class User(
    val id: String = "",
    val firstName: String = "",
    val lastName: String = "",
    val email: String = "",
    val image: String = "",
    val mobile: Long = 0,
    val gender: String = "",
    val profileCompleted: Int = 0): Parcelable
```

In an activity I called UserProfileActivity I store the mobile and gender into a hashmap, then call the Firebase function to update the Firestore Database. Here is a method of the activity. When the button "submit" is clicked, this code runs:

```
btn_submit.setOnClickListener {
            if(validateUserProfileDetails()){  //checks if entered credentials are valid
                val userHashMap = HashMap<String, Any>()  //creates the hashmap

                val mobileNumber = et_mobile_number.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }

                val gender = if (rb_male.isChecked) {  //these are radio buttons, only 1 clicked
                    Constants.MALE
                } else {
                    Constants.FEMALE
                }

                userHashMap[Constants.MOBILE] = mobileNumber.toLong()  //storing info in hashmap

                userHashMap[Constants.GENDER] = gender

                showProgressDialog(resources.getString(R.string.please_wait))  //starting a progress dialog

                FirestoreClass().updateUserProfileData(  //method in FirestoreClass 
                    this, userHashMap
                )
            }
        }
```

Now the called method that communicates with the database:

```
fun updateUserProfileData(activity: Activity, userHashMap: HashMap<String, Any>) {
        mFireStore.collection(Constants.USERS)  // collection named "users"
            .document(getCurrentUserID())  //getCurrentUserID() just gets the current user id 
            .update(userHashMap)  // hashmap used to update the user
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                when (activity) {
                    is UserProfileActivity -> {
                        activity.userProfileUpdateSuccess() //this just hides the progress dialog and finishes the activity in the UserProfileActivity
                    }
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                when (activity) {
                    is UserProfileActivity -> {
                        activity.hideProgressDialog()
                    }
                }
            }


}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
2021-12-27 02:35:38.727 14960-14960/com.example.myshopapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myshopapp, PID: 14960
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter it
    at com.example.myshopapp.firestore.FirestoreClass.updateUserProfileData$lambda-2(Unknown Source:7)
    at com.example.myshopapp.firestore.FirestoreClass.$r8$lambda$vs4EuaGwStcL-i3lXRUecduDHWM(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.example.myshopapp.firestore.FirestoreClass$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.onSuccess(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzm.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.0:1)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I have absolutely no clue where the null pointer exception is occuring... And funnily enough (this is important), the database DOES get updated properly so why is it crashing?? Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: You should use a debugger first to trace the code and see exactly where it crashes.  Also, for the purpose of posting to Stack Overflow, you should hard code as much you can and don't let folks talk for granted that all your variables and methods do what you think they do.

Comment: Also, maybe related or not, you should not pass an Activity instance down into your data layer, as you are going to leak that object and potentially cause other problems.

Comment: This is a [known google bug](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#december_09_2021)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This specific error has been showing up a lot lately, and seems to be due to an inconsistent nullability annotation in Firebase listeners.

Apparently Google is aware of [the issue](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#december_09_2021) and [may have recently fixed it](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#december_16_2021)

When adding an `onSuccessListener` for an `update` call in Kotlin it infers a non-null type for `it` (`Void` not `Void?`). This means if Firestore returns a null result (which would not be uncommon for a `Void` argument from java), it will raise the error you showed when it is cast to a non-null parameter. The solution is to update to the latest version that fixes this, or if you need an immediate workaround to specifically set the type to nullable, so to change

```kotlin
.addOnSuccessListener { 
    println("Updated doc")
}
```

to

```kotlin
.addOnSuccessListener { _: Void? ->
    println("Updated doc")
}
```

Comment: Had the same problem. You can also use `OnCompleteListener` instead of `onSuccessListener` https://stackoverflow.com/q/70568560/1621111

Comment: @KonstantinKonopko True, that is the solution I first used in my code too when I first ran into a [similar nullability issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70343009/how-do-i-call-a-java-method-that-takes-a-non-null-void-parameter-from-kotlin). It just adds an extra `if( task.isSuccessful )` line...