# Cloud Firestore addOnSuccessListener crashes with NPE

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

Every time the app has crashed after update some doc fields. These fields updated as expected, but crash comes in callback `addOnSuccessListener`. When I remove OnSuccessListener, this works fine. Any suggestions?

Upd: I've figured out that all my Firestore calls makes the app crash in `addOnSuccessListener`, so the reason is more global. Also using `addOnCompleteListener` instead of `addOnSuccessListener` works as expected.

Upd2: [Issue discussion and solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70492222/1621111)

```
fun setAppointmentStatus(docId: String, status: String, callback: (succeed: Boolean) -> Unit) {    
        db.collection(path)
                .document(docId)
                .update("status", status, "updatedAt", FieldValue.serverTimestamp())
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    callback(true)
                }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
2022-01-03 18:25:50.654 9378-9378/com.project.provider E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.project.provider, PID: 9378
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter it
        at com.biosensics.nula.cloud.AppointmentCloudHelper$setAppointmentStatus$1.onSuccess(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.biosensics.nula.cloud.AppointmentCloudHelper$setAppointmentStatus$1.onSuccess(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzm.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.0:1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that NPE?

Comment: @AlexMamo I guess it is internal Firestore SDK crash, so logger doen't show line number

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the entire stack trace?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen here you are

Comment: The stack trace shows the error as coming from your own code. Are you sure `callback` isn't `null`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen when I remove `callback(true)` the app also crashes with the same error

Comment: It's looks like all my Firestore calls make the app crash in `addOnSuccessListener`, so the reason is more global

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen what's your thoughts?

Comment: From the error message:

"Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter it"

It seems that `it` is required here, while you're not specifying it (sic). I'm not enough of a Kotlin expert to see exactly how to fix this in your code, but from `setAppointmentStatus$1.onSuccess(Unknown Source:2)` there isn't much room  for where the error comes from.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen please look at my update of the post

Comment: Good to hear your found the cause and solution @KonstantinKonopko! 

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you are trying to do, that seems to be to [add a timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp) to your document, you can do as follows:

```kotlin
// If you're using custom Kotlin objects in Android, add an @ServerTimestamp
// annotation to a Date field for your custom object classes. This indicates
// that the Date field has to be treated as a server timestamp by the object mapper.
val docRef = db.collection("objects").document("some-id") 

// Update the timestamp field with the value from the server
val updates = hashMapOf<String, Any>(
        "timestamp" to FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
)

docRef.update(updates).addOnCompleteListener { }
```

You only need to substitute the required variables of your own app. Changing “objects” to `path`, and “some-id” to `docId`.

---

To [Get File Metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/file-metadata#get_file_metadata) you can try this:

```kotlin
// Create a storage reference from our app
val storageRef = storage.reference

// Get reference to the file
val forestRef = storageRef.child("images/forest.jpg")

forestRef.metadata.addOnSuccessListener { metadata ->
    // Metadata now contains the metadata for 'images/forest.jpg'
}.addOnFailureListener {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
}
```

And if you want to learn more about [tasks](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task), I recommend reading this [blog entry](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-1.html) and it’s [kotlin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/file-metadata#kotlin+ktx) example where adding `OnFailureListener` is recommended to get the specific exception as a [NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) can have a variety of causes.